# Microsoft.Data.SqlCLient SqlParameter with MultishardCommand

Tags: c#, .net, sqlclient, system.data.sqlclient

I am working on some version upgrade and using new SqlClient namespace 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' : Version 5.1.1.
and 'Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client' latest version.

As i am using 'MultiShardConnection' and 'MultiShardCommand' and trying to add SqlParameter but facing syntax error 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter''.

It works well when i  use 'System.Data.SqlClient', but when I update with 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' i am getting syntax error.
So, any way i can add sql parameter using MultiShardCommand and 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' package?

I tried to debug through command parameter property. But looks like internally its dependent on 'Syste.Data.SqlClient' sqlparametercollection.

Comment: You have `System.Data.SqlClient` linked somewhere, you need to unlink it.